# Full game grid not outputting in Android Studios?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a puzzle application in Android Studios based on Hashi. however i am having trouble outputting the grid game map. I am double iterating through a 2d array and then outputting ovals in place of the numbers. I want it to output the grid off ovals with numbers inside as such -

```
1  0  0  0  1
0  2  0  0  2
2  0  3  0  1
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  2  0  2
```

However when i run my application in the emulator all that outputs is the first ovals in the top left hand corner of the emulator device.

```
public class boardView extends View {

    public float IslandX;
    public float IslandY;
    public int islandDiameter;

    private Canvas canvas;


    public boardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    int gameBoard[][] = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2}};

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            Paint Island = new Paint();
            Island.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            Island.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            float stepX = canvas.getWidth() / 5.f;
            float stepY = canvas.getHeight() / 5.f;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int R = 0; R < 5; R++) {
                    IslandX = i * stepX;
                    IslandY = R * stepY;
                    if (gameBoard[i][R] == 0) {
                        Island.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);

                    } else if (gameBoard[i][R] == 1) {
                        Island.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);

                    } else if (gameBoard[i][R] == 2) {
                        Island.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);

                    }


                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `canvas.getWidth() / 5.f;` returns a proper value?

Comment: what should it be?

Comment: at least not a `zero`

Comment: ive fiddled around with the value off it, all of which only output the first oval

Comment: could you post a picture of what is happening?

Comment: How do you post photos on here?

Comment: ![a busy cat] (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg) remove a space after `]`

Comment: it wont let me upload one.